# alter column from time with time zone to timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.2, alter

I am having trouble changing a column called `end_date` in a table called `key_request` from time with time zone to `timestamp` in my Postgres database . I have tried using the following code:

```
alter table key_request alter column end_date type timestamp with time zone using end_date::timestamp with time zone
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type time with time zone to timestamp with time zone
```

Any idea of how I can adjust this query to work?

Comment: I think you wrote it wrong, you want to convert from `timestamp without timezone` to `timestamp with timezone`, right?

Comment: nope the column is time with time zone and i wish to change to timestamp with time zone

Comment: OH! Sorry... Now I got it, I was reading `timestamp` instead of `time` all the time... lol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I woul do this in a series of steps

1. Alter the table, adding a new column `end_date1` as `time with time zone`
2. Copy the date from `end_date`(old) to `end_date1`
3. Alter the table, droping the old `end_date` column
4. Alter the table,reaming `end_date1` to `end_date`

Comment: that works fine but is there a way i can place that new column back in the position of the old column without deleting columns in between?

Comment: postgresql does not support changing the column order in an existing table. If you "REALLY" need it to be in a specific position (and the is no valid reason why you would need that) then you would need to recreate the entire table.

Comment: With the solution of @Roman Pekar you don't have to drop the column.

Answer (score 19):

you can do something like this:

```
alter table key_request
alter column end_date type timestamp with time zone using date('20130101') + end_date;
```

<kbd>[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/19650/3)</kbd>

Comment: This solution is better than the accepted on, as you don't have to drop the column. As well it corresponds to the PostgreSQL tutorial: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-change-column-type/

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `java.sql.Date` to `java.util.Date`

```
ALTER TABLE key_request ALTER COLUMN end_date TYPE timestamp without time zone;
```

If you have dependant views that relate to that table

1. drop views
2. change column type
3. recreate views

Solution coming from a java/hibernate approach while in type migration.

- `java.sql.Date` is translated to `date`
- `java.util.Date` is translated to `timestamp without time zone`