# Convert "time with time zone" to "timestamp with time zone" in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have to alter a table column from "time with time zone" to "timestamp with time zone".

I tryed

```
alter table mytable
alter column date type timestamp with time zone using date::timestamp with time zone
```

But i get an error that postgres cannot automatically convert these types. 
How can i do this? [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a215b)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18255845/3682599 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18255040/3682599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Winged Panther thank you very much ;)
Because time leaks the date its possible to convert with an constant date:

```
alter table mytable
alter column date type timestamp with time zone using date('20140101') + date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may specify `using null` as the conversion mechanism to start with empty values:

```
alter table mytable
  alter column date type timestamp with time zone
  using null;
```

Comment: so i have to truncate my table first? Is there a way to covert this column?

Comment: @0bmis: no need to truncate the rows, but for a conversion you'll have to provide your own method. A time does not contain enough information to make a timestamp (it lacks the date), and postgres cannot invent that information.